# Trying to find keywords and italicize them using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I tried to create something that will search the entire web page for certain keywords and italicize them using pure JavaScript. I haven't even attempted any thing to do with JavaScript lately (sidetracked), so I have no idea why this isn't working. I've tried googling but with no avail particular to my problem (everything I found was trying to change the `class` of an element as opposed to just the basic css property). All I really want to know is *why* this isn't working. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var str = document.getElementsByTagName("*").innerHTML;
        var n = str.match(/(Nautilus|Captain Nemo)/i);
        n.style.fontStyle = "italic";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
The Nautilus was a ship run by Captain Nemo.
</body>
</html>
```

Should produce the result:
The *Nautilus* was a ship run by *Captain Nemo*.

My un-experienced logic says that I should (try) to parse the entire document as a large string, then match that string for keywords using regex, then change the `style.fontStyle`.

Now, like I said, I haven't even touched JavaScript or even jQuery for a while now due to being busy, so I may be waaay off, but any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`n` is just a string here. It's not a node on the page. And only a node on the page can have styles that differ from their parents.  You can't simply tell a string to be italic. It's just a string and has no associated presentation information inherent to it at all.

So to do this, you must:

1. Find the text
2. Wrap the text in a `<em>` element, for each match
3. Insert the results HTML string back into the document

Or in JS:

```
// get all body content as a string
var str = document.body.innerHTML;

// find all magic words and wrap them in a <em> tag
var result = str.replace(/(Nautilus|Captain Nemo)/ig, "<em>$1</em>");

// set all body content HTML with new processed content
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/2px7m/

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
//Use g so it will be global  
var regex= /(Nautilus|Captain Nemo)/ig;

str[0].innerHTML = str[0].innerHTML.replace(regex, "<i>$1</i>");
```